# AES decryption Algorithm

Tags: cryptography, aes

I'm going to make a long story short. It's been a while that I want to implement my own AES encryption/decryption program. The encryption program went well and encrypting without any error or strange output (Since I have compared my program's output with a working commercial one and result was the same).

Wikipedia was (is) my guide in this implementation within which I read "A set of reverse rounds are applied to transform ciphertext back into the original plaintext using the same encryption key."

There are couple of modules that I implemented:

1. Add round key
2. Shift rows
3. Sub bytes
4. Mix Column

I also implemented couple of reverse implementation of the above modules:

1. Reverse shift rows
2. Reverse Sub Byte
3. Reverse Mix Column

NOTE: I didn't implement reverse round key since, It's XOR ing the plaintext with the encryption key, and reverse of XOR is XOR itself (correct me if I am wrong)

So I putted this modules in the reverse order that I did encryption, but never I got my plain-text back:

```
expandkey128(key);
rev_subbytes(data);  
rev_shiftrows(data);
addroundkey(data,key,10);

for(int i = 9; i>= 1; i--) { 
    rev_subbytes(data); 
    rev_shiftrows(data);
    rev_mixColum(data);
    addroundkey(data,key,i);
}

addroundkey(data,key,0);

// Please note that I also did from 0 to 10 ,
// instead of 10 to 0 and didn't workout
```

And also I thought , maybe I should not implement reverse model of the modules, maybe I have to use those modules that I did encryption with, only in reverse order; well guess what? didn't work! :

```
expandkey128(key);
addroundkey(data,key,0);

for(int i = 1; i<= 9; i++) {
    subbytes(data); 
    shiftrows(data);
    mixColum(data);
    addroundkey(data,key,i);
}

subbytes(data);
shiftrows(data);
addroundkey(data,key,10);
```

So here is the question: what is wrong? || what is the correct sequence of applying these so called modules or functions if you will?

Comment: did you calculate your s-box correctly, cause you cannot use the same one which you are using for the encryption.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box
This comment is missing in the english Version in wikipedia. take a look at the spec directly: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf You have do calculate the inverse s-box to decrypt.

Comment: Yes actually at rev_subbytes I have Inverse S-box of Rijndael

Comment: there's a great tool ot there: http://www.cryptool.de/ In that you can do any transformation by hand. Maybe you have to debug each step, maybe the tool will help you with that to verify each step.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your order of operations seems wrong. I think you want this:

```
expandkey128(key);

addroundkey(data,key,10);
rev_shiftrows(data);
rev_subbytes(data); 

for(int i = 9; i>= 1; i--) { 
    addroundkey(data,key,i);
    rev_mixColumn(data);
    rev_shiftrows(data);
    rev_subbytes(data); 
}

addroundkey(data,key,0);
```

For more details, see [my stick figure explanation of AES](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html) with its accompanying reference implementation.

**WARNING**: As mentioned in [Act 3, Scene 2](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_Zfbv3mHcYrc/Sre5MXZdxnI/AAAAAAAABoE/KzWFtoYJbKU/s576/aes_act_3_scene_02_agreement_576.png), [there be dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons) in writing your own AES implementation for production use.

Comment: I wouldn't use a own implementation for aes either. Nice Agreement ;)

Comment: Well I'm not going to use it anywhere, was just for fun!
and I tried your order which didn't work, also I checked the link (http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf), says different order

Comment: It works on my machine and in my implementation :). If you have some time, download my C# implementation and step through it and compare each step to your implementation. Note that the order I gave is effectively the same as Figure 12. I just prefer it in the order I gave to make it clear that it is reversing everything. It took me a few trials comparing my output to the round-by-round output from the Rijndael book to make sure I had things right. You might simply have a small error in one of your inverse functions. I'd recommend going slowly over each round as your next step.

Comment: thx Jeff the bug was in my Inverse sBox implementation, and your order of putting statements is totally correct, appertained again